# Input operator Polynomial

Tags: c++, input, io, stream

I am trying to create an input operator for a Polynomial class. However, my input operator is not reading my first coefficients and everything after the first exponent. It is basically reading the first term without coefficients. Here is my code:

```
std::istream & operator>> (std::istream & in,
                           Polynomial & aPoly)
{
    double tempCoefficient;    // temporary storage for coefficient
    char ch;               // variable that contains results from peek()
    char dum;            // removes useless symbols like '+' and 'x'
    int tempExponent;          // contains current exponent for coefficient
    bool moreTerms = true; // variable that tells when the terms run out
    bool negativeCoefficient = false;  // tells when coefficient is negative
    aPoly.coefficients.resize(0); // Clears aPoly before inserting user input

    in >> ch ;


    if (ch == '-')
    {
        negativeCoefficient = true;
        ch = in.peek();
    }

    else
    {
        in.putback(ch);
    }

    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        in >> tempCoefficient;
        if (negativeCoefficient)
        {
            tempCoefficient *= -1;
            negativeCoefficient = false;
        }
        ch = in.peek();
    }



    if (ch == 'x')
    {
        tempCoefficient = 1.0;
        in >> dum;

        if (in.peek() == '^')
        {
            in >> dum;
            in >> tempExponent;
        }

        else
        {
            tempExponent = 1;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        tempExponent = 0;
        moreTerms = false;
    }

    aPoly.coefficients.resize(tempExponent + 1);
    aPoly.coefficients[tempExponent] = tempCoefficient;

    if ((in.peek() != '+') || (in.peek() != '-'))
    {
        moreTerms = false;
    }

    while (moreTerms)
    {
        ch = in.peek();

        if (ch == '+')
        {
            in >> dum; // '+'
        }

        else
        {
            negativeCoefficient = true;
            in >> dum; // '-'
        }

        ch = in.peek();

        if ( (ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9') )
        {
            in >> tempCoefficient;
            if (negativeCoefficient)
            {
                tempCoefficient *= -1;
                negativeCoefficient = false;
            }
            ch = in.peek();
        }

        else
        {
            if (negativeCoefficient)
            {
                tempCoefficient = -1.0;
                negativeCoefficient = false;
            }

            else
            {
                tempCoefficient = 1.0;
            }
        }

        if (ch == 'x')
        {
            in >> dum;

            if (in.peek() == '^')
            {
                in >> dum;
                in >> tempExponent;
            }

            else
            {
               tempExponent = 1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            tempExponent = 0;
            moreTerms = false;
        }



        if ((in.peek() != '+') && (in.peek() != '-'))
        {
            moreTerms = false;
        }

        aPoly.coefficients[tempExponent] = tempCoefficient;

    }
    return in;

}
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Please state your question/issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem here

```
if ((in.peek() != '+') || (in.peek() != '-'))
```

where the condition is always true.

Further down in the code you use `&&` which works better.

Comment: Thank you but it is still not taking the first coefficients:(